# Swift: Populate collectionView with data of Web Service

Tags: ios, swift, grid, populate

I have an array of object, and I want to populate a collectionview and custom gridview  (image + text).
Can you help me?

I create the array and when I try to load, the tabledata.count is 0 or nil

This is a part of code.

```
class BusinessController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {


var tabledata:[BusinessMkp]
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadCollectionViewData()

}

func loadCollectionViewData() {
    let client = WebServiceMobile()

    client.opPing(){
        (response: PingResult?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if response!.cpPingResult==true{
            client.opGetBusiness("", name: ""){
                (response: ArrayBusinessMkp?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                self.tabledata=(response?.cpElencoBusinessMkp)!
                print(self.tabledata.count)
            }
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(self.tabledata.count)
    return self.tabledata.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: Business_adapter = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Business_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Business_adapter
    cell.business_text.text = tabledata[indexPath.row].cpName
    //cell.business_image.image=UIImage(named: tabledata[indexPath.row].cpLogo)
    return cell
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedItem=tabledata[indexPath.row]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

Comment: Did you implement numberOfSections?

Comment: no, only numberOfItemsInSection

Answer (score 1):

After loading your data in `client.opPing` you need to

```
self.collectionView!.reloadData()
```

then your count will not be nil

Comment: don't work, I try it but I get an error : "Ambiguous use of 'collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)'"

Comment: implement numberofsections and return 1